# Application defined or object defined error - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

the following code gives me an Application defined or object defined error on the bold line. I set the range; however, apparently excel can't read it. I am not sure why that error appears. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

```
Public Sub specialattention()
'Loop to check whether issue needs spcial attention
Dim n As Variant
Dim nend As Range
Dim nrng As Range
Dim nnow As Date
Dim ninterval As Integer
ninterval = Sheets("Ranges").Range("AB3").Value
nnow = Sheets("Issues Database").Range("N5").Value
Set nend = Sheets("Issues Database").Range("M1048576").End(xlUp)
Set nrng = Sheets("Issues Database").Range("M6", nend)
For Each n In nrng
    If n.Value = "1" And nnow - n.Offset(0, 1).Value >= ninterval Then
        n.Offset(0, 2).Value = "1"
    Else
        n.Offset(0, 2).Value = "0"
    End If
    'Color Cells that need special attention
    If n.Offset(0, 2).Value = "1" Then
            Dim xrng1 As Range
            Dim xrng2 As Range
            Set xrng1 = n.Offset(0, -11)
            Set xrng2 = n.Offset(0, -1)
            **Sheets("Issues Database").Range(xrng1, xrng2).Interior.ColorIndex = 19**
        Else
            Dim xrng3 As Range
            Dim xrng4 As Range
            Set xrng3 = n.Offset(0, -11)
            Set xrng4 = n.Offset(0, -1)
            **Sheets("Issues Database").Range(xrng2, xrng3).Interior.ColorIndex = 2**
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Break the line into smaller lines with assignment and see which gives the error.  As one possible example, `Set r12 = Sheets(..).Range(..)` followed by `Set intr = r12.Interior` followed by `Let intr.ColorIndex = 19`.  Discovering which of such lines gives the error should help tracking it down.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the ranges passed to .Range are valid ranges, your code should work.

Based upon your code, the first instance:

`Sheets("Issues Database").Range(xrng1, xrng2).Interior.ColorIndex = 19`
should be fine.

However, your second instance:

`Sheets("Issues Database").Range(xrng2, xrng3).Interior.ColorIndex = 2` is referencing ranges that are not in scope since you are reusing `xrng2` which is defined in a different logic path.

Presumable updating your second problem line to this:

`Sheets("Issues Database").Range(xrng3, xrng4).Interior.ColorIndex = 2` will give you your expected behavior.